# Getting to a BIOS screen on HP Laptop with Ubuntu OS installled

Tags: boot, usb

I have an HP Laptop fairly new and I have Ubuntu OS loaded on it.  I want to boot through a USB but I cannot access the BIOS using ESC of F10.

Comment: Watch the screen closely at power-up. The magic "summon the BI9S" key may not be ESC or F10.

Comment: And, you have a very short time to hit the magic key. Beware short timeouts.

Comment: Accessing the BIOS menu is a feature of your motherboard and isn't related to any operating system. If you need more help with this, read your laptop documentation or motherboard documentation. If you still need help, consult with the support options for your particular hardware.

Comment: You need to press & hold (*at the appropriate time*) the key scanned for by your *firmware*, and only someone with your exact device will know what that is. I have devices that require me to hold & press a key when device/laptop is OFF & it awakens & asks if i want to boot external media (*it won't otherwise*) so use the specific way your *firmware* was designed to work.

Comment: Typically HP - <kbd>escape</kbd>  + <kbd>F9</kbd> for UEFI boot menu, <kbd>F10</kbd> for UEFI/bios settings But check your manual. You may need to do a full power shutdown, remove battery, hold power switch to drain all power they you have just enough time to get into UEFI settings to turn fast boot off. Fast Boot can be so quick you have not time to press any key.